# How can I align a paragraph at the top of a pdf page in MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

Currently in my pdf page I have an image logo on the right hand side and a title on the left hand side. I want the title in the left hand side to be top aligned. Or atleast both the icon and the paragraph on the same line. How can I do this? I am new to Migradoc. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use something like  spaceBefore or spaceAfter as a work around. Else you will have to place the paragraph in a table and then align the table.
Example way of space before will be like,
     paragraph1.Format.SpaceBefore = "1cm";